# get_permalink wrongfully returns only year and month and not all the link

Tags: permalinks

This is very strange and I don't know why. I am developing a theme, and in some areas I am manually creating different related news. They work perfectly, because I can start a WP_query almost everytime I need it.

In one case I can't, so I'm using functions to get posts data, starting from their ID. As soon as I set the permelinks to "pretty" (in my case year/month/name) in the admin panel, the get_permalink() function stopped working.

Instead of returning the whole post url, it stops after the month.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I'm very simply using `$permalink=get_permalink($id);`

Comment: please post the full code of the function or template.

Comment: But where did $id come from? post the surrounding code, even if you think it isn't relevant

Comment: Just to double check can you confirm you are using %postname% for the /name portion? It won't work if you typed %name% when you set permalink structure and you should also see issues elsewhere as well.

Comment: I think that the problem are the permalink themselves. I have to rebuild them.